How to Open parent app from ShieldAction Extension
When I tap on one of the buttons in the ShieldAction extension I want open the parent app  Is there any way of doing this using the Screen Time API?
class ShieldActionExtension: ShieldActionDelegate {
    
    
    override func handle(action: ShieldAction, for application: ApplicationToken, completionHandler: @escaping (ShieldActionResponse) -> Void) {
        // Handle the action as needed.
        switch action {
        case .primaryButtonPressed:
            if let appURL = URL(string: "xxxx://") {
                //open parent app

            }
            
            completionHandler(.none)
        case .secondaryButtonPressed:
            completionHandler(.close)
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
.....
}

This tells me it can't be done
Open parent app from ShieldAction extension in iOS
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/app-lock/id6448239603
But This app does it. Does anyone know how to do it
i try use  UIApplication.share.openURL, but not support
